# Temporary Fix for Leaky Sink Gasket Washer - Putty?

Tags: kitchens, leak, sink

all. I have a kitchen sink gasket that is leaking small drips between the rubber gasket/washer and the screw ring. It looks like the glue between the pieces and somewhere along the cardboard ring is coming apart.

Is there a way to re-glue or seal the pieces together and stop the leak without having to take things apart? Maybe like a putty or sealable tape that someone can recommend?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the other answer. There is not going to be any fix that you can somehow kludge on top of the already leaking basket that will provide a reliable solution. The correct solution is to simply take apart the existing assembly and repair it with a proper sealant.

Note that on most sinks there is to be some plumbers putty installed under the upper rim of the drain basket that gets squeezed down against the rim of the hole from the top side of the sink. This putty is what really seals the joint that is leaking on your sink. The washer that you see underneath the sink is just a bearing surface for the big round ring nut that threads onto the outside of the drain basket.

In many instances the drain basket may be best replaced completely. They are not particularly expensive and can be purchased at hardware stores and home centers.

Keep in mind that if you should choose to ignore the advice here and attempt to fix the leak by globbing on silicon sealer, epoxy or other type of material you will make it much harder to remove the basket for the proper fix when the kludged repair fails.

Comment: 100% true and correct. I will add that you will need a new tailpiece washer (it might come with the new basket, if you go that way), and maybe a new tailpiece (I don't like the looks of that tape wrapped around there).

Comment: @Jimmy-FixIt - unfortunately some people believe that Teflon tape goes on every threaded part when in fact as in this case it makes zero difference.

Comment: Thank you. Per the suggestion, I'm going to replace the basket.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the drain basket, clean the surfaces, and reinstall with a new gasket.